# How to change title attribute returned by comments_popup_link()?

Tags: hooks, comment-meta

I can change label of comments by altering Comment(s) from parameter of following function: `comments_popup_link('No Comments;', '1 Comment;', '% Comments;');`
But, seems that title attribute is returned from core modules.
Suggest me to alter title attribute without editing core modules.

Comment: Have you tried using localization to change that? An .mo file doesn't need to have more than one string in it... You could create a custom .mo file that "translates" the string 'Comment on %s' to whatever you want it to say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the function `comments_popup_link()` you will see the following code at the end:

```
$title = the_title_attribute( array('echo' => 0 ) );

echo apply_filters( 'comments_popup_link_attributes', '' );

echo ' title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __('Comment on %s'), $title ) ) . '">';
comments_number( $zero, $one, $more );
echo '</a>'; // last line
```

Note the call to `__()`, the translation function. We can filter `'gettext'` to change the result. Since we do not want to run our filter on every translation – that would be too slow – we start the filter when the hook `'comments_popup_link_attributes'` is called:

```
add_filter( 'comments_popup_link_attributes', 't5_cclta_init' );

function t5_cclta_init( $attrs )
{
    add_filter( 'gettext', 't5_cclta_change_title', 10, 3 );
    return $attrs;
}
```

Now we need just the real filter function:

```
function t5_cclta_change_title( $translated, $text, $domain )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 10 );

    if ( 'default' === $domain && 'Comment on %s' === $text )
        return 'Talk about %s';

    return $translated;
}
```

And now the title attribute says: *Talk about The Post Title*.

Answer (score -1):

Like they said it's hard coded into WP core, and it's best practice to not mess with the core. However the title is located in `<span class="screen-reader-text">Post Title</span>` just use CSS to hide it.

`.screen-reader-text{
    display: none;
}`